# Intercepting form submission and displaying results in cakephp without JS

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In my `Manager` controller's `add` action I want to intercept the form submission, perform a search using the submitted data, and (if the query returns any results) display a list of results to the user.

My question is: what is the best way to display the results to the user?  Should I just redirect to a different action (say `search`), or is there a nice way to display the data while remaining in the `add` action (session flash maybe)?

I know this can easily be done with the `ajaxHelper` and I am approaching this from that angle too, but I also need this functionality for my non-javascript users.

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

badp,

you could just have a look at one of the generated (by `cake bake controller ...`, resp. `cake bake view`) controller methods named `edit` and look at the dataflow there.
It should be easy to adept it to your needs from there, as you can compare the dataflow and its outcome visually.

Comment: you, sir, are the man. looking at the `edit` action gave me exactly what I needed to accomplish this.  thank you!!